# Redirect directories to individual s3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Laravel application hosted on a domain. I have several dynamic directories ie:

example.com/directory

example.com/random

example.com/moon

I would like each of these directories to resolve to a different s3 bucket while masking the URL (I want to see the URL above, not the s3 bucket URL). What's the best way to accomplish this? I could possibly create a primary bucket and host example.com on it and create routing rules on that s3 bucket to redirect to the other s3 buckets (I think). What do those routing rules look like? I was unable to find directions in the AWS documentation that showed how to redirect to other buckets. Is there another, more simple way to go about this?

It's worth noting the Laravel application may not need to be involved in the actual routing as much as using the AWS sdk to dynamically configure the directories.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Route53 along with S3 enabling static website hosting.

For detail configuration about static website hosting in S3, you can take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax).

After that choose Route53 as a service in AWS Console.

Select your hosted zone and add a CNAME recordset, in the value field enter the S3 bucket endpoint url and in the Name field enter the url that you want to point to the S3 bucket.

For using Route53 you can read this [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a CloudFront (CF) distribution with **three different origins**. Then each origin would respond to different [Origin Path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath) which would lead to different buckets.

`example.com` could be defined in Route53, with **Alias A** record to the CF distribution. The benefit of using CF with S3 is that you not only can speed up your website (CF is CDN), but also you can keep your buckets and objects **private**:

- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)

Comment: I’ve tried this approach but the issue I’m having is the root domain (example.com) tries to handle all of the requests in its bucket. So when I go to example.com/directory it looks for a folder named directory in the root domain’s bucket instead of using the bucket associate with the origin path for /directory

Comment: @JaysonLane You would have to make new question specifically dedicated to that issue with details of your setup. But the use of CF is the correct approach.